# Were any Japanese defendants at the far east war criminal trials after WW2 IQ tested by the allies?

Tags: world-war-two, japan, ww2-pacific-theater

Since the Americans [tested the IQ](http://miyaguchi.4sigma.org/gradytowers/nazi.html) of the defendants of the Nuremberg trials I was wondering if there was an analogous deed done to the Japanese war criminals after the WW2.
I can't find anything related to the IQ testing of the Japanese leaders during the far east war criminal trials.

> Were any Japanese defendants at the far east war criminal trials after
> WW2 IQ tested by the allies?

Comment: Would be interesting to see them. However, if any tests were considered, it's painfully obvious that native Japanese tests would have to be used, and I don't think anything suitable was available. For Nuremberg defendants German version of Wechsler-Bellevue was used, but it's Japanese version was not available until 1950, while first tests for Japanese adults were developed in 1947

Comment: Because IQ tests for *sanity*, not *morality*. If two populations are struggling over certain resources (in this case, over certain regions of the world, be it Europe, or the Pacific), and one of them, whilst prevailing over the other, also decides to take advantage of the situation, and eradicate it completely, so that it might rule unhindered, such a decision might be considered *immoral*, but not *illogical*, from the perspective of one's *self-interest*; however, if one population decides to exterminate another *for no discernible reason*, that is grounds for even *deeper* concern.